# How do I pay for classes as a non-degree student?

Tags: masters, tuition

I've already earned my degree (B.S. in Neuroscience, Psychology and Music), but need to take some pre-requisite classes before applying to a Masters in Physician Assistant Studies program. These courses are going to end up costing about $10,000 total. I imagine I'll need to take out another loan, but who should I talk to first? The school? The bank?

I know very little about financing this kind of thing and am trying to avoid getting taken advantage of.

I'm be applying to school in the north eastern U.S.

Comment: Please clarify 1. _I've already earned my degree_ What degree? BS? 2. Is Masters P.A. Masters Physician Assistant? 3. Where is your location? U.S.?

Comment: I updated the description for clarification.

Comment: This might also be a good question for http://money.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

You might try enrolling in a university as a [non-degree seeker](http://admissions.utexas.edu/apply). Such programs allow people who already have a Bachelor's degree to take additional courses for official credit but not towards any specific degree. These programs are common and a good way to add to a transcript in order to meet minimum admissions requirements for future programs to which you might apply.

Comment: This doesn't address the question of financial aid.  Many forms of financial aid are restricted to degree-seeking students and/or to undergraduates.

Comment: @NateEldredge, one question per question, and I reserve the right to choose which question to answer in a multi-question question until it gets closed or edited.

Comment: I don't see multiple questions.  The only question I see is about financial aid.  Title: "How do I ***pay*** for classes...?" Body: "I imagine I'll need to take out another loan, but who do I talk to first?"  I don't think the question is asking about program options at all.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I guess I read it more broadly as "How do I become permitted to pay to take some make-up classes since I already have a degree, am not eligible to apply for the degree I'd like, and otherwise don't know how to enroll?"

Comment: @BillBarth, I'm strictly interested in paying for the classes, not how to register for them.

Answer (score 0):

You're not eligible for federal student loans, as a non-degree student taking pre-reqs.  You can talk with banks, but they seem to be out of that business (student loans) these days.  I asked my bank reps one time, just out of curiosity and to perhaps have some extra options to consider, just in case.  So, you'll likely pay the 10k out of pocket immediately, so you had better find a temporary job to help pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would talk to the schools you want to apply for; some schools will admit you to a graduate program with an agreement that you will take these required courses.  If you have a school that will work with you, you may be able to take these courses while being considered as a Master's student (and so be eligible for funding/financial aid).